# How to wrap a line of list items in HTML

Tags: html, css

The HTML below is what I'm working with. I want it to be in a line rather than in list format.

1. If I use float:left, how do I make the div get bigger (vertically) when it "line wraps"?
2. If I set display:inline, how can I get it to line wrap for real between the list items rather than on spaces that might not exist (as seen below)?

---

```html
 <div class="singleTiddlerList">
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button center">Hide All</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button center">Show All</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button center">Refresh</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">ResizerMacroPlugin</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">ResourceMacro</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">saveBackupPlugin</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">singleTiddler</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">sliderMacro</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">toggleBackstageEdit</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;" class="button">TopbarPlugin</a></li>
 </div>
```

---

**Edit:** Just for your info, it only needs to work with Chrome and Firefox. It isn't a customer website or anything like that, just a personal file (actually a [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)).

Comment: first of all, you should use a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element to nest `<li>` elements

Comment: Can you rephrase your questions? Maybe give some examples of what you want.

Comment: @AlexDemchak, what difference does it make? Just wondering.

Comment: For semantic correctness. HTML has the ability to express lists of things, and it helps the Google robot, screen readers, and all manner of users who don't care solely about the presentation of the site understand your content better. y using semantically correct markup, you are embedding extra information in your text. By using ul/li you are communicating to the consuming application that the information is a list, and not just "something" (who knows what) that is some text inside an arbitrary element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` on the `<li>`s.

If you need support for IE less than version 9, use this hack as well:

```
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the cross-browser issues which you can encounter by using 'display:inline;', I suggest that you use 'float:left;' instead.

Here's the working piece : http://jsfiddle.net/tHjap/4/

Addressing the point you brought up about the 'div' (in this case 'ul') getting bigger all that needs to be done is to set the width to be 'auto'

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `overflow: hidden;` on the container. This works due to some oddity in the specs. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html or http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/ for mor informationn
2. Not sure if I understand the question right, but maybe you want `white-space: pre;` on the `a`s. This will prevent line breaks inside them.